# How to send json and call a function in chrome.runtime.sendMessage?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

In my contentscript.js I have this:

```
chrome.extension.sendMessage({ action: "isBlacklist", url: tablink, title: title });
```

Here is my background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request) {
  if(request.action== "isBlacklist") {
    console.log("url: ", request.url);
    console.log("title: ", request.title);
   }
}
```

But I want to write like this and I don't know how to write in chrome extension:

```
var data={"url":url,"title":title};
chrome.extension.sendMessage({ action: "isBlacklist",data:data});
```

and in background:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request) {
   //I don't know how to write but this is a example 
   //var fn = null;
    //if(typeof request.action === 'function'){
     // fn = request.action;
   //}
 }
```

and then I can call a function:

```
function isBlacklist(data){
   console.log("url: ", data.url);
   console.log("title: ", data.title);
}
//another function if we send message more in contentscript.js.
```

So if we can write like this, we can call multi function instead of like here:

```
   if(request.action== "action1") {
     method1();
  }
 else if(request.action== "action2") {
     method2();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have all functions in an object:

**background.js**

```
var Actions = {
    isBlacklist: function(){
        //A good way to use data, `this` is equivalent to `data`
        console.log("from content script...", this);
        console.log("url: ", this.url);
        return false
    },
    isBatman: function(){
        console.log("from content script...", this);
        console.log("url: ", this.url);
        return "I am Batman"
    }
};

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if(typeof Actions[request.action] === "function"){
        sendResponse(Actions[request.action].call(request.data));
    }
});
```

**contentScript.js**

```
var data = {"url": "google.com", "title": "The title"};
chrome.extension.sendMessage({action: "isBatman", data: data}, function(value){
    console.log("From background.js ->", value)
});
```